# How to disable serializeuser and deserializeuser for specific strategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have code like this:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        console.log('serializing user ' +user._id);
        return done(null, user._id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
      console.log(id);
        Users.findById(id, function (err, user) {
            console.log('deserialize user ' +id);
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, username, password, done) {
            Users.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
                    if(err){
                        return done(err);
                    }

                    if(!user){
                        console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
                        return done(null, false);
                    }

                    if(!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                        console.log('Invalid Password');
                        return done(null, false); // redirect back to login page
                    }

                    return done(null, user);
                }

            );
        })
    );

    passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        function (req, username, password, done) {
            Users.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
                if(err){
                    return done(err);
                }

                if(user){
                    console.log('User already exists with username: '+username);
                    return done('User already exists', false);
                }
                else{
                    var newUser = new Users();

                    newUser.username = username;
                    newUser.password = createHash(password);

                    newUser.save(function (err) {
                        if(err){
                            console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);
                            throw err;
                        }
                        console.log(newUser.username +' Registered Successfully');
                        return done(null, newUser);
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    );

    var isValidPassword = function (user, password){
        return bCrypt.compareSync(password, user.password);
    };

    var createHash = function (password){
        return bCrypt.hashSync(password,bCrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
    };
```

The problem is, when client sign-up new user and registered successfully. client will be automatically authenticated.
How to make client is still not authenticated until he/she is log-in??

So the flow I want is:
 1. client register new ID
 2. Client still not authenticated until he/she is login
 3. client login
 4. Client is authenticated now

Comment: Can you provide the code of your sign-up and login routes?

Comment: The problem is solved right now. Only need to set session: false to sign-up passport use.